# any algorithm or function in python to convert hollow stl("file format") object into filled(solid) stl object(file formate)

Tags: python, numpy, open3d, openscad

is any function or algorithm to convert hollow.stl object into filled.stl object using python

I want to convert any hollow obj.stl to fill (solid) obj.stl using python

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: you could try trimesh module